# Need help for regex

Tags: javascript, regex, text

I'm using regex to look for answer choices and their descriptions.
Until now it's working great, but the problem is that I can't figure out how to include multiple line description without including next Choice.

My current regex:

```
^(Choice [A-I] \(.*\) +(?:is incorrect. )?($|\r?.*))
```

Test cases:

```
Choice B (Predominance of eosinophils) zfdfdfbhdfdfdf
fgdfgdfgdfdfdfhd fgdfgdfgdsgsf
sgsgdfgdf gdfgdfgdfgdfgd gdfg
Choice C (Monosodium urate crystals) fghfdghfghfghfh
Choice D (Spirochetes) is incorrect fghfghfghfghfghf
Choice E (Predominance of polymorphonuclear cells)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vC3uY8/2)

I need the two random text sentences after Choice B to be also included in Choice B match, but without including Choice C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
(Choice [A-I] \(.*\) )(((?!Choice)[^\n]+[\n]?)+)?
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/hZ4nC5/4)

**Explanation**

- `(?!Choice)`: String don't beginning with "Choice"
- `[^\n]`: any letter, except "\n"

Comment: Worked like charm! Also used this principle in other - similar situation. Thanks!